# regex: find select clause from a CTAS statement

Tags: python, regex

I have a requirement to fetch select statment from a CTAS SQL statement.

Eg)

```
create table table1 as select * from table2
```

Python code:

```
rgxselect =  re.compile(r"(((?:select|with)[\s\S]*))",re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)
s = rgxselect.search(item)
    if s:
        selectclause = s.groups()[0]
```

This works for first example
but in case of brackets like below example

```
create table table1 as (select * from table2)
```

I would like to either get

```
(select * from table2)
```

or

```
select * from table2
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to try `\b(?:select|with)\b[^()]*`

Comment: Thanks Wicktor, it works  for simple select clauses but if I have complex select statements like select id,case when id in (1,2,3) then ok end as status from table2 it would capture only till first (. The best solution would be capture (select clause) including start and closing parenthesis

Comment: Nested parentheses regex is not achievable in Python `re`. For the fone-level deep nested parentheses case, you can use `\b(?:select|with)\b[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fone-level deep nested parentheses case, you can use

```
\b(?:select|with)\b[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWQ80u/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:select|with)` - `select` or `with`
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\([^()]*\)` - `(` + zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` + `)`
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`